# Embed Youtube Player in a web page stops play when minimize web browser - Android Device

Tags: android, audio, flash, youtube, embed

Embed Youtube Player in a web page stops playing audio when minimize web browser(Chrome) - Android Device

Is there any javascript for this page to keep playing de video when minimized?

My site is https://uiamano.com/?page_id=126

On pc works fine, but not in Android device :(

Thanks!

Dante

I´m actually searching the web for the code